# How to use a SQL request with YII framework

Tags: php, sql, yii

I am new with YII framework so, sorry for my beginner level.

I want to know how to insert a SQL request inside this framework ?

**Like**

```
SELECT *
FROM tab_a as a, tab_b as b
WHERE a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$command = $connection->createCommand("SLECT * FROM tab_a as a, tab_b as b WHERE a.id=b.id");
$row = $command->queryRow();
```

Comment: Sorry I use this inside the controler code or view code ?

Comment: You can use inside the controller if you want to render the records otherwise use in view.